# Java Convert string to double

Tags: java, string, double

When I pass small value in text field

```
double q = Double.parseDouble(pqty.getText());
System.out.println("hiii    "+q);
```

It's give same output like 10000
but when I passed 10000000 the output is changed my q variable print like this 1.0E7.

I want it 10000000.00 like this.

Comment: why don't you print `pqty.getText()` ?

Comment: if it is about printing it out `System.out.printf("%s%.2f\n", "hiii    ", q);`

Comment: System.out.println(); is for just checking I am doing calculation with q